# What's the difference between include and require in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a class in puppet if I have the following code:

```
class A {
  require B

....
}
```

I get circular dependencies error. If I have:

```
class A {
  include B

....
}
```

everything works fine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are very different things, actually. To say `require B` means `B` must come before `A` (and, therefore, can lead to circular dependencies if something in `B` turns out to `require A`). And if `B` is not included at all, it will lead to missing dependencies error.

On the other hand, `include B` just says `B` will be applied whenever `A` gets applied: it says nothing of the order between them.

Comment: Doesn't `require B` actually means that `B` must come before `A`?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski Uh, yes. :)

Answer (score 10):

This was just asked (and answered) on the puppet mailing list:

> The difference is evident when the
>   catalog needs to be applied. With
>   include you have evaluated its
>   contents at the time of the include -
>   but any resources must be depended on
>   explicitly after the include. With a
>   require - the dependency is created
>   for you - but you have to be careful
>   and ensure that this is your desired
>   result

- Ken Barber in [Require vs Include?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/l81Srf-9PHM/CephI2jGeqgJ)