# How to create a user with Puppet

Tags: puppet, users

I am trying to create a user with Puppet but everything I have been trying has failed.

I am trying to create a user named "capistrano" that will be placed in the "www-data" group. I have done the following configuration.

```
class capistranoDeps::user {
    user { "capistrano":
        ensure => present,
        comment => "Capistrano user",
        gid => 33,
        shell => "/bin/bash",
        require => Group["capistrano"],
    }
    group {"capistrano":
        ensure => present,
    }
}


class capistranoDeps::config {
    require capistranoDeps::user
    # Set permissions on webserver directories
    file {"/var/www/":
        ensure => directory,
        owner  => "capistrano",
        group  => "www-data",
        mode   => "775",
    }
...
}
class capistranoDeps {
    require tools
    include capistranoDeps::user,capistranoDeps::config
}
```

When I try to execute this config on my host, I get the following error :

```
root@app1:/etc/openvpn# puppet agent --server=puppet.domain --no-daemonize --verbose
notice: Starting Puppet client version 2.6.2
info: Caching catalog for app1.domain
err: Could not run Puppet configuration client: Could not find user capistrano
```

The user has not already been created on the host as it is Puppet's job to do so. The examples I have found all over seem to be the same as this but since this isn't working, I am definitely missing something.

Comment: Never really used Puppet but the line 'user { "capistrano":' looks like you're trying to log in as the cap user, before it's been created, try changing that to a user that does exist and see what happens

Comment: That is the line that's supposed to tell puppet to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"require" does not do what you think it does -- it actually creates a dependency.

You want to use "include" instead in class capistranoDeps::config

```
include capistranoDeps::user
```

For more information, also see this question:

[What's the difference between include and require in puppet](https://serverfault.com/questions/281085/whats-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-puppet)

Comment: Wow, that actually worked ! Thank you very much :) Puppet can be very strange sometimes but such an awesome piece of software !